# Shooting object directly at click java libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to get my player to shoot a spell and it travels to where ever the player clicked. I can easily accomplish this by doing the following.

```
    if(position.x >= destination.x - 1 && position.x <= destination.x + 1)
        reachedX = true;
    if(position.y >= destination.y - 1 && position.y <= destination.y + 1)
        reachedY = true;
```

However if the players origin is at, for example, 0,0 and I click at 10,300 then it travels right and up but when the spell reaches an x of 10 it travels directly upwards. I want the spell to travel at an angle that it will reach the x coordinate at the same time as the y coordinate. Here is an image showing what happens and what I want to happen.

[image: Image example]

Comment: Can you post the class definitions and declarations of position and destination as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first picture it looks like the spell goes 45° until it reaches the right x-coordinate. This sounds like the x and y speed are equals, no matter where the destination point is.
You shuld instead have a direction and depending on that a x and y speed.
For that you first need to get the point, the player is clicking.
Therefore you can implement `InputProcessor` and it's `touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)`.
The `screenX` and `screenY` arguments are given in screen coordinates (pixels) and therefore need to be converted to your world-coordinates. This can be done using the `camera` or the `viewport` and it's `unproject(Vector2 screenCoords)`. This method returns a `Vector2` giving the world-coordinates.
Now you need to find out the direction `Vector2` between you and the clicked point. The direction `Vector` is calculated like this:

```
new Vector2(otherPos.x - myPos.x, otherPos.y - myPos.y).nor();
```

This returns the normalized direction `Vector` between the two points.
Now you only need to move the spell by `dir.x*spellSpeed*delta` in x-direction and `dir.y*spellSpeed*delta` in y-direction and it should look like in your second picture.